# How do I generate a vector during each iteration of loop, store data, and then delete that vector?

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am trying to create a vector of vectors in my program. I wish to have a double loop; the inner loops checks for a certain condition, and if that condition is met, a value is stored in my vector. Once the inner loop runs its course, that "temp" vector is stored in the main vector. My idea was to clear my "temp" (inner) vector, but vector.clear() deletes everything in my main vector as well. This is my vector code:

```
vector <int> vectortestInner;
vector <vector<int> > vectortestOuter(10);
```

I populate my vectors here:

```
void vectorTest()
{
    for (int i=0; i<vectortestOuter.size(); i++)
    {           
        for (int j=0; j<vectortestOuter.size(); j++)
        {
              vectortestInner.push_back(j);
        }
            vectortestOuter[i]=vectortestInner;
        //vectortestInner.clear();
    }   
}
```

and attempt printing the contents like this:

```
  for(int i=0; i<vectortestOuter.size(); i++)
      {
           for (int j=0; j<vectortestInner.size(); i++)
           {
               cout<<vectortestInner[j]<<endl;
           }
       }
```

So far, it seems to be printing 0s, (when I want it to print 1-10), and if I call clear();, it just outputs empty lines.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Populating (or repopulating since that's what your first function does can be done with

```
// remove any global declaration of vectortestInner since we won't use it

void vectorTest()
{
    for (int i=0; i<vectortestOuter.size(); i++)
    {   
        std::vector<int> vectortestInner;
        vectortestInner.reserve(vectortestOuter.size());         
        for (int j=0; j<vectortestOuter.size(); j++)
        {
              vectortestInner.push_back(j);
        }
        vectortestOuter[i]=vectortestInner;

        // vectortestInner ceases to exist here
    }   
}
```

This locally constructs `vectorTestInner` in every iteration of the outer loop, so it will be destructed at the end of the iteration as well.  The `reserve()` call avoids multiple resizing (but is specific to the fact your inner loop is, in total, going to append `vectortestOuter.size()` elements).

Yes, this reconstructs `vectortestInner` every time.  But that is not actually any worse than clearing and repopulating every time (since those are the most significant operations done in construction and destruction).

To print the elements of your vector of vectors, you actually need to refer to them.   Your code has a flaw in that (somehow) you are assuming `vectorTestInner` magically provides a means of accessing elements of `vectorTestOuter`.   That is not so.

```
  for(int i=0; i<vectortestOuter.size(); i++)
  {
       for (int j=0; j<vectortestOuter[i].size(); j++)      // also using j++ here, not i++
       {
           cout<<vectortestOuter[i][j]<<endl;
       }
   }
```

There are other inefficiencies in your code that I haven't addressed.   Rather than using `[]` consider using iterators as well.    I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the temporary vector (`vectortestInner`) in your inner loop, not a vector contained in the main vector (`vectortestOuter[i]`).

```
for(int i=0; i<vectortestOuter.size(); i++)
 {
     for (int j=0; j<vectortestOuter[i].size(); j++)
     {
          cout<<vectortestOuter[i][j]<<endl;
     }
}
```

With the printing function changed, the clear of `vectortestInner` should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately if I do that, nothing prints at all (but my program runs). If I hit CtrC to quit, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you replace both instances of `vectortestInner` with `vectortestOuter[i]`?

Comment: As written, the inner loop will (after enough iterations) give undefined behaviour.   Increment `j` rather than `i`.    (This was a problem in the OPs code too - just not one asked about).

Comment: @Peter: Good catch, I totally missed that. (edit: Fixed)